# Is there any traffic API available which can give me data for real time as well as past data(for few months)?

Tags: api, traffic

I know about mapquest traffic API http://platform.beta.mapquest.com/traffic/, bing - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441730 but they all provide for real time no past data.
please suggest any type of help will be appreciated